# Formatting birth and death place and date

Tags: dates, formatting

I would like to use the proper form for indicating the birth date and place and death date and place for the author of a book review. For example, would this be considered correct:

Erich Neumann (b. Berlin, 1905; d. Tel Aviv, 1960)

Comment: Use a style guide, or look at publications for guidance.

Comment: More precisely: use **the** style sheet of the publication in which the review is supposed to appear. There is no one 'proper' way of doing it that would apply to all English-language publications.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style. Here are some examples from reputable sources. Note that the style you used in the example is identical to that in *The Harvard Concise Dictionary of Music and Musicians*.

> *Encyclopedia Britannica*
>
> > Theodore Roosevelt, bynames Teddy Roosevelt and TR, (born October 27, 1858, New York, New York, U.S.—died January 6, 1919, Oyster Bay, New York).
>
> *Basketball: A Biographical Dictionary*
>
> > Ron Briley ANDERSON, William Harold "Andy" (b. September 11, 1902, Akron, OH; d. June 13, 1967, Fort Lauderdale, FL)
>
> *The Harvard Concise Dictionary of Music and Musicians*
>
> > Draghi, Antonio (b. Rimini, ca. 1634; d. Vienna, 16 Jan. 1700).
>
> *Biographical Dictionary of American Educators*
>
> > BARR, Arvil Sylvester. B. January 10, 1892, Selvin, Indiana, to Elisha and Ellen (Bolin) Barr. M. April 18, 1914 , to Lillian Whittinghill. Ch. none. D. May 12, 1962, Madison Wisconsin.
>
> *The New Biographical Dictionary of Film: Sixth Edition*
>
> > Robert Aldrich (1918–83),
> >  b. Cranston, Rhode Island